# Binding to Global Catalog takes longer than binding to directory server

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I have a single forest with single AD domain. There is only domain controller serving the forest. I am unable to explain the latency in connecting to global catalog.

Here are the details:

```
Domain name: mydom.test
DC name: dc.mydom.test
DNS is installed on DC machine.
```

By opening LDP.exe, I can connect in less than couple milliseconds to all of following host and port combinations

```
mydom.test:3268
mydom.test:389
dc.mydom.test:389
```

Following combinations takes up 6 to 7 seconds

```
dc:3268
dc:389
dc.mydom.test:3268
```

I am more interested in last scenario as it impacts us more. Verified that ping response for dc, mydom.test, dc.mydom.test is very fast.

I tried above scenarios on DC machine and on different machine joined to mydom.test domain. I see the same behavior.

I am unable to explain the reason for multi second latency. Any suggestions on how to debug this problem and what could be causing this?

Comment: I took wire shark trace and found that there were two netbios queries for dc.mydom.test. host:port specified in ldp.exe was dc.mydom.test:3268. Both Netbios queries took multiple seconds to resolve.

I disabled netbios over tcp on network configuration applet on both DC and client machine, then connection to GC is as fast as LDAP now.

Do not know why Netbios queries are being made. What should I do to make those NetBios queries resolve fast.

Comment: Asked the same question in technet directory services forum, and I found the reason for the delay. Here is more info [link] https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/kb/2439492. Hope this helps someone.